# Execute some code in the page from a custom control in WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, user-controls, custom-controls

I've created a custom user control. If I created an instance of this control in a page called Page1. I need some code to be executed in Page1 according to some action inside the user control. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Can you post some code, e.g. the xaml source code of your control inside Page1?

Comment: They both need to have access to the same code/scope. One way is to have them both bound to the same viewmodel, so that the action in a usercontrol calls something in the viewmodel which is seen by and reflected on the page.

Comment: @igrali I'm not using MVVM. If some code is executed in Page1 according to a change in a custom property in the user-control, then I'm satisfied. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your user control, define an event:

```
public event EventHandler MyEvent;
```

In the page, hook that event:

```
void Page_Load(...)
{
  userControl.MyEvent += MyCode;
}
```

In your control, execute the event when it wants to run code on the page:

```
void SomethingHappened()
{
  var e = MyEvent;
  if (e != null)
  {
    e(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  }
}
```

That's it.